# Taking screenshot of iphone device without using UIGetScreenImage() from private API

Tags: iphone, screenshot, iphone-privateapi

I just wanted to ask whether there is a way to take the screen shot of iPhone device. I don't want to use the private API. I want to take the screen shot of entire screen, not just application. Is there a way to do it? please post it. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're supposed to use the `AVFoundation` Framework now instead of `UIGetScreenImage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to use Quartz functionality to achieve this

Comment: I'd be interested to know how you take screenshots on an iPhone by pressing keys on your Mac.

Comment: Thanks for the useful post robin. actually i want to build an application which can capture the screen programatically. So it will be very nice of you if you can throw some light on it.

Comment: sorry about that you can follow this link http://www.tuaw.com/2010/07/21/devsugar-rip-uigetscreenimage/ for your purpose